# Convert full-width Japanese text to half-width (zen-kaku to han-kaku)

Tags: ruby, text, unicode, cjk

In PHP it's possible to convert double-width characters to single width with the function `mb_convert_kana`. They call it "convert zen-kaku to han-kaku". For example, I have a string to convert:

```
dbl = "ＢＯＸ"
```

and I'd like to find some method like this

```
dbl = "ＢＯＸ".convert_to_half_width # dbl is now "BOX"
```

Is there a way to do this in Ruby?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I use a combination of the Ruby built-in `NKF` and `String#tr`

```rb
require 'nkf'
dbl = "ＢＯＸｶﾀｶﾅ"
dbl = NKF.nkf('-X -w', dbl).tr('０-９ａ-ｚＡ-Ｚ', '0-9a-zA-Z')
# dbl now is "BOXカタカナ"
```

This has the added benefit of transposing half-width katakana to full-with katakana as well.

Comment: it doesn't work for me.

NKF.nkf('-X -w', "カタカナ")
 => "カタカナ"

Comment: @KaranBamniya This answer transposes full-width 0-9, a-z, A-Z to half-width ASCII characters, while transposing *half-width* katakana to *full-width* katakana. If you want to transpose full-width katakana to half-width, use `NKF.nkf('-Z4w', 'カタカナ') => "ｶﾀｶﾅ"`

Answer (score 2):

Well, it's not pretty and it only works for Romaji (could be extended to deal with other characters) but it worked for me:

```
title = "ＢＯＸ"
englishReplacements = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890"
japaneseReplacements = "ａｂｃｄｅｆｇｈｉｊｋｌｍｎｏｐｑｒｓｔｕｖｗｘｙｚＡＢＣＤＥＦＧＨＩＪＫＬＭＮＯＰＱＲＳＴＵＶＷＸＹＺ１２３４５６７８９０"

converted = title.tr(japaneseReplacements, englishReplacements) 
# title is now "BOX"
```

Comment: I need to convert half to full, and seems nkf cannot do that. So this really helped.

Answer (score 0):

There's a gem for that: [hz_on_fly](https://github.com/jinzhu/hz_on_fly)

Answer (score 0):

I think the [Moji](https://github.com/gimite/moji) gem ([Japanese documentation](http://gimite.net/gimite/rubymess/moji.html)) would be well suited for this, as well being a very useful Japanese language gem in general (works with Ruby 1.8 and 1.9):

```
require 'moji'

dbl = Moji.zen_to_han("ＢＯＸ")
# => "BOX"
```